# How to create a custom embedded servlet container for SpringBoot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm trying to create a custom embedded servlet container for SpringBoot 2. I've created an implementation of the `ServletWebServerFactory` and `WebServer` interfaces. In my application, I explicitly exclude the embedded Tomcat from the `spring-boot-starter-web` and then manually feed my custom factory class to the `SpringApplication` constructor. When the `start()` method of my `WebServer` implementation is called, I feed my `ServletContext` to all of the `ServletContextInitializer`s that were passed to the `getWebServer` method of the factory.

I can see Spring loading my factory and grabbing my `WebServer` object correctly when I call the `run()` method of the `SpringApplication`. However, the startup fails with this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
```

What am I missing? Is there another place I should be passing the `ServletContext` to?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue with calling the `onStartup(ServletContext)` method of the `ServletContextInitializer`s when they are passed to the `getWebServer()` method of my `ServletWebServerFactory` passing in my custom, initialized `ServletContext` - without waiting for the `start()` method to be called on the `WebServer` implementation. While this resolves my issue I have not idea wether it is the right thing to do or not, I'd still like to hear from a SpringBoot expert.